# How to publish an CoreData entity extension?

Tags: swift, swiftui, wrapper

I'm using CoreData in my SwiftUI app. To have some better handling I added some wrappers to the CoreData classes like this:

```
extension Category {
    public var wrappedName: String {
        name ?? ""
    }
}
```

This is working fine till now. But now I need to observe this wrappers also and I use the `Category` as an `StateObject`. Therefor I wanted to Publish it like this:

```
extension Category {
    @Published public var wrappedName: String {
        name ?? ""
    }
}
```

This is triggering the error: `Non-static property 'wrappedName' declared inside an extension cannot have a wrapper`

If I remove the `@Published` I get an error for the `@StateObject`:

```
Property type 'Category?' does not match that of the 'wrappedValue' property of its wrapper type 'StateObject'
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: You can't use @Published on a whole extension as far as I know and what you have is a read-only computed property so it is unclear when it should publish anything.

Comment: Sorry, the extension was copied to the wrong place, its of course in front of the wrappedName